# Crystal report failing on Azure fileshare

Tags: c#, azure, crystal-reports

Hi I am getting this exception while generating crystal reports on Azure from my localhost.

My code is

```
loRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, lsFolder);
```

Value for lsFolder is

`\\abc.file.core.windows.net\public\development\PDFs\abc.pdf`

Please help me where and what is breaking. Please do note, I am reading rpt files from the same storage

`\\abc.file.core.windows.net\private\development\rpt\xyz.rpt`

And I am getting the below error:

> The system cannot find the path specified. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The
>   system cannot find the path specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 249:        { Line 250:            lsReturn = lsPDFURL; Line 251:
>   loRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
>   lsFolder); Line 252:
>   loRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
>   HttpContext.Current.Response, true, fsFileName); Line 253:        }
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified.
>   ]
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions
>   pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext) +0
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext) +2325
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext) +1199
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext) +385
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType
>   formatType, String fileName) +443    SOReport.ExportSOReport(String
>   fsSONumber, Boolean flgSave, String fsFileName, PDFLogDetail
>   foPdfDetail) in c:\VSO
>   Project\WebSites\Main\PDFGenerator\App_Code\ExportSOReport.cs:251
>   SOReport.Export(HttpRequest Request, Boolean canSave, String
>   nexgenWebsiteURL, String sopoNumber, String databaseName) in c:\VSO
>   Project\WebSites\Main\PDFGenerator\App_Code\ExportSOReport.cs:69
>   CrystalReportAccess.GenerateCrystalReport(HttpRequest request) in
>   c:\VSO
>   Project\WebSites\Main\PDFGenerator\App_Code\CrystalReportAccess.cs:44

### Updates

1. Password in table's logoninfo is blank.
2. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The system cannot find the path specified. even if i am using  loRpt.ExportToHttpResponse().

Comment: Try ruling out File/Folder access issues by using FileInfo on the rpt file and doing an exists on it. If that works, try creating a file in the output folder using FileInfo again.

Comment: Also check for UNC issue - check if paths like "C:\..." works.